# How to stop flex from stretching to 100% width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have a section with 2 columns pulled to center in flexbox, but for whatever reason the container doesn't wrap itself around them horizontally and instead fills the whole page.

What can I do to make the section wrap around the text (with expected padding of 1rem)?

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}

section {
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to top right, goldenrod 0%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, goldenrod 100%) 2;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
}

section>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section>div:first-child {
  border-right: 2px solid goldenrod;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

section>div:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <p>Line First</p>
    <p>Line Second</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Line First</p>
    <p>Line Second</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mjp1qozs/3/

Comment: `display: inline-flex;` ?

Comment: But then you lose the centering.

Comment: `max-width: fit-content; ` use this trick

Answer (score 13):

```css
max-width: fit-content;
```

works as well as

```css
display: inline-flex;
```

use first if you don't need another `max-with` (also [fit-content is partially supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content))

or use second if `inline` element is ok for your case

Answer (score 4):

The answer was to change `display` to `inline-flex`. Thank you, Temani Afif!

Answer (score 3):

With `display: inline-flex`, as suggested in the comments above, you achieve the shrink-wrap behavior that you want, but you also lose the horizontal centering. So you solve one problem, but create another one.

Instead, just make the parent a flex container with `justify-content: center`. That solves both problems with just two lines of code.

```css
body {
  display: flex;           /* new */
  justify-content: center; /* new */
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}

section {
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to top right, goldenrod 0%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, goldenrod 100%) 2;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
}

section>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section>div:first-child {
  border-right: 2px solid goldenrod;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

section>div:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <p>Line First</p>
    <p>Line Second</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Line First</p>
    <p>Line Second</p>
  </div>
</section>
```